# Ring Buffer/Circular Array Implementation in C

Tags: c, arrays, buffer, circular-buffer, circular-list

There are a bunch of previous posts and examples for implementing a circular buffer in C, but I many of them include structures and that's a bit too complex for the task which I am trying to do.

The task is relatively simple, to print out the last 10 commands that a user has input, similar to the the bash function `history`. My code is below:

```
void make_history(char **entry) {
    static char past_entries[10][10];

    static int index = 0;
    int sz = sizeof(past_entries)/sizeof(past_entries[0]);

    if(strcmp(entry, "history") != 0) {
        strcpy(past_entries[index], *entry);
        index = (index + 1) % sz;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        printf("%d. %s", i+1, past_entries[i % sz]);
    }
}
```

There are two main issues that I am having for this implementation. One is the that the history would produce values up to 10, even though a user has only entered less than 10 commands -- which can probably be fixed with the `for` loop.

The second problem is that although the buffer will wrap around after reaching the value of 10, it will not update the most recent input command. Again, this problem is likely solved from the `for` loop, which can point to the different beginning points.

Thank you for any and all help. I can provide more details if necessary.

Comment: This does solve the first issue, but still cannot figure out how to start the loop of the array at the most recent entry and wrap around to the final entry

Comment: so if you input 10 entries, the output should be the those 10 entries ordered from most recent to least recent. at the 11th entry, the output would be still be the 10 most recent entries, eliminating the first entry that was input

Comment: Try to debug it yourself. Ring buffer is one of the easiest ones